# How to create function that will return a certain string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do this javascript challenge and I just can't seem to get it. Very new to all of this and just trying to learn.

Create a function called evenOrOdd that takes in a number as a parameter. If the number is even return a string equal to "The number is even". If the number is odd return a string equal to "The number is odd".

Here is my code:

```
function evenOrOdd (number){
  if (number==="even"){
    return "The number is even";
  } else if (number==="odd"){
    return "The number is odd";
  }
}
```

Comment: check out the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modulus:

```js
function evenOrOdd(number){
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    return "The number is even";
  } else {
    return "The number is odd";
  }
}

console.log(evenOrOdd(1));
console.log(evenOrOdd(2));
console.log(evenOrOdd(13));
console.log(evenOrOdd(16));
```

Comment: Code golf! `function evenOrOdd(n){ return "The number is " + (n % 2 ? "odd" : "even") }`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I think I can do better than that!!!! :P `evenOrOdd = n => "The number is " + (n % 2 ? "odd" : "even");`

Comment: @AlecFenichel Don't forget about the extra spaces :P

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 On that note, `evenOrOdd` is way too long too :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if...else` you can also use a so-called [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
function evenOrOdd (number){ return "Number is " + ((number%2===0) ? "even" : "odd"); }
```

To check for odd or even, you need to use modulus 2 operator, which returns 0 if the number is even, and 1 if the number is odd.

Answer (score 1):

```
function evenOrOdd (number){
  if (number%2 === 0){
    return "The number is even";
  } else{
    return "The number is odd";
  }
}
```

- 5 % 2 = 1
- 4 % 2 = 0
- 3 % 2 = 1
- 2 % 2 = 0
- 1 % 2 = 1

http://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/481-the-mod-function.html